# SharePoint 2016 excel WebPart input back ground color

Tags: web-part

[image]I set up a sharepoint using 2013 with excel webparts and the input back ground was black.  Now the site has been moved to 2016 and the excel webpart input back ground is white.  I have seen only how to change the webpart back ground but nothing on how to change the webpart input back ground.  It is the space left after setting the webpart workbook display named item.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Need screenshots of what you are experiencing. Is it a custom webpart or OOB?

Comment: Added screen shot, it is just a standard Excel webpart.

Comment: surely someone has had this problem as well.

Comment: anyone, someone, please.

Comment: No one has had this problem but me?